# custom field value as shortcode parameter

Tags: shortcode

i am using a plugin (download monitor) to display downloads via shortcodes. the shortcode has a single parameter, which is the download's ID: `[download id="123"]`

i'd like to be able to modify the download ID parameter within the shortcode via a custom field value.

i've created a custom field - `ur-single-form-id` - and also a shortcode for it `[ur_single_form_id]` via the following function:

```
function ur_single_form_id() {
    $cf = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ur-single-form-id', true );
    $var = '<p class="your-class">' . $cf . '</p>';
    return $var;
}
add_shortcode( 'ur_single_form_id', 'ur_single_form_id' )
```

this was in the hopes of being able to do something like this: `[download id="[ur_single_form_id]"]`

unfortunately things aren't parsed as expected, and i get an error saying "download not found".

how can i implement this such that the download ID is populated within the download monitor shortcode using the custom field value?

thanks

Comment: I think it easier to take original `[download]` shortcode and make your own with it. First of all, you send shortcode as a string (its always a string) and download shortcode don't fire `do_shortcode()` function or other filter to retrieve your value. Second thing: `[download id="[ur_single_form_id]"]` this construction will never work, because you use square brackets inside square brakets. Wordpress will find starting `[` of download shortcode and will find first `]` which is the end of your shortcode. Just paste a code of download shortcode if you need help with it)

Comment: @anton thanks. the default download monitor code looks like this: [download id="123"]

Comment: Is your goal to change id value dinamically using your own shortcode? Just asking, because I see some `<p>` tags inside your shortcode, just like you want to format it.

Comment: that was just for testing purposes. intended goal to change download id dynamically via the custom field value

Comment: I will add it as answer, but it's not tested, so write a comment if it will not work.

Comment: ok great. will test immediately and report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never worked with this plugin, just downloaded it from repository and found that they provide a filter for id value.

Add this filter callback function to your functions.php file. 
`[download id="auto"]` - will use id from your post meta (hardcoded meta name)
`[download id="123"]`  - will use id 123

```
function download_shortcode_custom_id($id, $atts = []){
     if(!is_numeric($id) && $id = 'auto' ):
        //change 'temp' post meta name with your own
        $post_meta = get_post_meta(get_queried_object_id(), 'temp', true);
        $post_meta ? $id = $post_meta : null;
     endif;
     return $id;
}

add_filter('dlm_shortcode_download_id', 'download_shortcode_custom_id', 10, 2);
```

As a second option you can set your post meta name as id value
`[download id="temp"]` - will use this post meta name to retrieve an id
`[download id="123"]`  - will use id 123

```
function download_shortcode_custom_id($id, $atts = []){
     if( !is_numeric($id) ):
        $post_meta = get_post_meta(get_queried_object_id(), $id, true);
        $post_meta ? $id = $post_meta : null;
     endif;
     return $id;
}

add_filter('dlm_shortcode_download_id', 'download_shortcode_custom_id', 10, 2);
```

Comment: added both functions exactly as your demo, but dd not work. used following short codes to test:

[download id="auto"]
[download id="ur_single_form_id"]
[ur_single_form_id]

results:

[Download not found]
[Download not found]
72555

included my custom field shortcode to ensure printout correctly, which it does.

Comment: note: i renamed the second latter function of course

Comment: I installed this plugin to understand how it's actually works. I updated my answer with 2 option. Both work and retrieves download link by post_meta value as id, I already tested it. I preffer second option, because post_meta name there is not hardcoded.

Comment: thanks for the extra legwork! will test again and report.

Comment: just tested - both methods work! thank you!

Comment: You're welcome)

Comment: i have several post metas that are numeric IDs hence must use first method?

i'm also using an addon for download monitor - gravity forms lock [link](https://a.tmp.ninja/oMzvzHCU.zip). for that, the shortcode, which i must include in the same post is like this: `[dlm_gf_form download_id="ur-single-download-form-id"]` where `ur-single-download-form-id` would represent the post meta name.

Comment: i dug around the addon code and think found a similar callback for the shortcode id para, but not quite sure what i'm missing:

`function download_shortcode_custom_form_id($id, $atts = []){
     if(!is_numeric($form_id) && $form_id = 'auto' ):
        //change 'temp' post meta name with your own
        $post_meta = get_post_meta(get_queried_object_id(), 'ur-download-form-id', true);
        $post_meta ? $form_id = $post_meta : null;
     endif;
     return $form_id;
}
add_filter('dlm_gf_form', 'download_shortcode_custom_form_id', 10, 2);`

Comment: If you have several post meta and you want to use them both with `[download]` shortcode, second option is just right for you. It will get a value from any post meta, as you pass post meta name as id attribute. `[download id="POST-META-NAME-1"]`, `[download id="POST-META-NAME-2"]` etc. Of course any post meta should return a valid download id, otherwise you will see "download not found"

Comment: i understand. will implement the second method!

as for the forms version, i found this:
`// hijack the download shortcode
add_shortcode( 'dlm_gf_form', array( $this, 'shortcode_dlm_gf_form' ) );`

perhaps similar way to insert post meta into form version of shortcode?

Comment: Make another question about this, please.

Comment: [new question here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/387803/post-meta-value-as-shortcode-parameter)