# post meta value as shortcode parameter

Tags: php, shortcode

i am using a plugin (download monitor) to display downloads via shortcodes. also using an addon for download monitor - [gravity forms lock](https://a.tmp.ninja/oMzvzHCU.zip). for that, the shortcode, which i must include in the same post is like this: `[dlm_gf_form download_id="download-form-id"]` where `download-form-id` would represent the post meta name.

i'd like to be able to modify the download form ID parameter within the shortcode via a custom field value.

i found this in the 'gravity forms lock' add-on for download monitor:

```
// hijack the download shortcode add_shortcode( 'dlm_gf_form', array( $this, 'shortcode_dlm_gf_form' ) );
```

i'm hoping there is a method to filter or hijack the shortcode for the forms as there is for the standard download shortcode.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> // hijack the download shortcode add_shortcode( 'dlm_gf_form', array( $this, 'shortcode_dlm_gf_form' ) );

This line just adds a shortcode from a class. I checked this plugin's class and they didn't provide any actions or filter. You can try to modify original code of this plugin for your purposes only. I don't see any other solution. I don't know what this plugin even do, just looking at source code and trying to understand the logic, so my advice is not tested)

Open file `dlm-gravity-forms.php` 
From the line 156 you will see this code:

```
// the download_id is a required attribute
if ( ! isset( $atts['download_id'] ) ) {
    return 'Download Monitor - Gravity Forms Error: No download_id set!';
}
```

It's a check if download_id is set. Just after this if statement you can add the same code from previous question with the same logic - if download_id is not a number - get post meta value from post meta with a name you pass in download_id attribute:

```
    if( !is_numeric($atts['download_id']) ):
        $post_meta = get_post_meta(get_queried_object_id(), $atts['download_id'], true);
        $post_meta ? $atts['download_id'] = $post_meta : null;
    endif;
```

Save changes ;)

Comment: that did it! hopefully they'll implement actions or filter, or will find a way to hijack it without modifying actual plugin.

Comment: thanks again!!!

Comment: Don't forget that if update for this plugin will be available and you update - this changes will be overriten

Comment: yes, aware of that, and contacted the plugin dev regarding future updates and the possibility of implementing a filter as in the core plugin. thanks!